# Budgies eating only seeds

Tags: diet, feeding, birds, budgerigar

My budgies are eating only seeds. I tried feeding them soaked wheat and chickpeas. They did not eat it. Also I am trying to feed tomato, carrot and apple, however they are not eating it.
Is there any trick to feed them other food?

Comment: How much seed do they have? Are you sure they’re not touching the fresh stuff? They may not finish it but you’ll see beak marks if they’ve tried it. How many budgies? Is all the food on the same tray?

Answer (score 1):

There are different little methods for changing bad eating habits of parrots. As you realize, it is important for a parrot to have a varied diet. Distribute several types of granules, peas, rice, dough, fruits and vegetables, so as to present 7 to 8 different ingredients.

You can try to make him discover new foods by putting your parrot in a quiet place on a table and spread out a handful of foods that you want your birds to discover then start playing with these foods, bring them to your mouth and make pretending to eat them, ... very often the bird will come to play and eat with you.

In the event that your bird has absolutely no knowledge of certain food, it may not recognize it as food. In this case, you can present him with small pieces in his usual bowl with foods that he knows well. He will be confident and may accidentally taste and adopt this unknown food. Or you can also do the opposite by giving it a bowl full of new foods and adding a few treats that your bird likes (nuts, sunflower seeds, ...)
One technique that works well in my case is to cut fruit or vegetables in front of him and give small pieces of the food to be introduced by hand outside the cage, as if it were a reward.

Offer him the new food in the morning bowl. In general in the morning the birds are more hungry that will be able to be forced to taste it.
Offer the new food in a toy or between the bars of the cage. This may be enough to excite his curiosity.
Eat the food to be tested in front of your bird and get excited about what you eat. This tactic generally works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try feeding them with leaves? Parsley and dandelion leaves were among the preferred treats for my budgies, when I had them. Arrange the leaves as a bouquet or make them not movable by any means (tie them to the side of the bird cage), provide them to the budgies.

Once they understand that food is more than seeds, they might try other foods also.

---

Try presenting any new foods the same way as known food. Instead of seeds, place carrot and apple small cuttings in their food tray.